# Why does \includegraphics[\varone]{\vartwo} not compile?

Tags: macros, graphics, conversion, programming, shell-escape

I want to convert each EPS image imported from within the input file to a PDF version and save it with its original name separately. The code below simulates the real condition in which we don't want to make heavy modification. So I have to renew the definition of `\includegraphics` by appending the conversion process at the end.

The conversion make use of an external template (`template.tex`) that  is created on the fly when compiling the `inputfilename.tex`. For each invocation of `\includegraphics` in `inputfilename.tex`,

```
\immediate\write18{latex -jobname=#2 \unexpanded{"\def\varone{#1} \def\vartwo{#2} \input{template}"} && dvips #2 && ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None #2.ps}
```

will be invoked. It uses the template `template.tex` and gets two parameters `\varone` and `\vartwo` from `#1` and `#2` of `\includegraphics`.

However, the following code does not compile with errors that you can see by yourself. The code must be compiled with `pdflatex -shell-escape inputfilename`.

```
% inputfilename.tex 
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{template.tex}
\documentclass[preview,border=0pt,graphics]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\makeatletter
%\define@key{Gin}{width}{}
%\define@key{Gin}{scale}{}
%\define@key{Gin}{height}{}
%\makeatother
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[\varone]{\vartwo}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx}



\let\temp\includegraphics

\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
    \temp[#1]{#2}%
    %\immediate\write18{latex -jobname=#2 "\def\noexpand\varone{#1} \def\noexpand\vartwo{#2} \noexpand\input{template}" && dvips #2 && ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None #2.ps}%
    \immediate\write18{latex -jobname=#2 \unexpanded{"\def\varone{#1} \def\vartwo{#2} \input{template}"} && dvips #2 && ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None #2.ps}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-a}
\caption{A}
\label{fig:A}
\end{figure}
A \ldots

\chapter{B}
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.75]{example-image-b}
\caption{B}
\label{fig:B}
\end{figure}
B \ldots

\chapter{B}
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-c}
\caption{C}
\label{fig:C}
\end{figure}
C \ldots

\end{document}
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`keyval` goes to some effort *not* to expand macros in the argument list so

```
\edef\z{\noexpand\includegraphics[\varone]{\vartwo}}\z
```

not

```
\includegraphics[\varone]{\vartwo}
```

Comment: Or, more briefly, `\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\varone]{\vartwo}` since the file name is expanded.

Comment: @egreg, actually mine's more brief, as `\z` is shorter than `\expandafter`

Comment: Mine has less tokens. `:P`

Comment: @egreg I know:-)